# iPhone -- create UITabBar programmatically?

Tags: iphone, uitabbar

How does one do this?

Note that I do *not* want a controller.  Just a tab bar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`UITabBar *aTabBar = [[UITabBar alloc] initWithFrame:aFrame];`

You’ll probably need to refer to [the class documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for instance methods like `-setItems:animated:`. Also, see the [`UITabBarDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarDelegate_Protocol/) protocol.