# iphone: creating view controller programmatically on the run time

Tags: ios4

This is what I am trying to do, when my apps load, user is presented with a bunch of options ( These options are coming from a server) and when user selects one of those options I have to create a new tab bar controller with number of tabs, their name, their layout all coming from a server in the xml format. So the first question is it possible to do this in iphone, that is create all the view controller programmatically on the run time, if yes can you please point me to some reference, i have been searching in google, but may be my search terms are not good, I am not getting back any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, it's possible. Anything that can be done using IB can also be done in code. In your particular case, you have to subclass the `UITabBarController` class and then use the `viewControllers` property to populate the bar at runtime, depending on your XML.

Please refer to the class reference at [Apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more information.

Possible duplicate of [iPhone -- create UITabBar programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221133/iphone-create-uitabbar-programmatically)