# how to add a button in tabbar

Tags: iphone, button

how to add a user customize button in tab bar items, just like app: evernote for iPhone.
the "New note" button is in the middle of the four tab bar items.
i can't attach image now, the evernote screenshots can be found in this link:

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/evernote/id281796108?mt=8

tap the middle button can launch a modal view controller for new note.

how to implement this function?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of answers on SO, should have tried searching

[how to create a tabbar programmatically and adding buttons on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220978/how-to-create-a-tabbar-programmatically-and-adding-buttons-on-it)

[iPhone -- create UITabBar programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221133/iphone-create-uitabbar-programmatically)

[Programmatically Setting UITabBar Titles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056354/programmatically-setting-uitabbar-titles)

Comment: thank you for your reply, but i think there's a little bit difference. i want a customize button for a modal view controller, this button is not belong to the tab bar items, it's just position in the middle of tartar items, and there isn't any relationship with tarbar controller, just like the "Add" button in the app "EverNote".

Comment: You asked for "tap the middle button can launch a modal view controller for new note." Just use first link to make a button on tab bar, then for its selector action give the modal view's instance.